# How to limit users to ONLY input one specific language in a Text Field?

Tags: php, html, tags

So I'm having this Text Field that users can input anything based on the languages installed on their keyboard. I'm asked to limit them to only use Arabic. The example is like this: http://epay.sanjesh.org/Payment/Customer.aspx?id=WcAGgjZVzEk=

In that link, you are only allowed to input Arabic language. Even if your keyboard language is set on English, it still writes Arabic.
I was thinking of using lang="ar". 
Is that correct? if it is, then how should I use it?!

Comment: [Here ya go buddy](http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/) - Google Input Tools.

Comment: It is a useful tool man, but it doesn't give me the answer. I have to set my Text Field in HTML to only accept Arabic inputs. Your link converts the languages alphabets.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy dont know if it is intended or not...but if I typed chinese it did show chinese instead of the default set language..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the input language just by setting the lang attribute. But there are tools that can help you. Take a look at [this](http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/) link for example.

Combine the two for the desired effect.

Comment: Did you visit the link I put in the question?
Just go there and type something while your keyboard is set to English. And see what happens!

Comment: Yes i did. Did you try to switch the 'keyboard icon' dropdown to the keyboard option?

Comment: I did. Ok the text field in the link I gave works like this. You have to put your Keyboard language to english. And when you write in it, it only writes arabic alphabets. On the other hand, if you change the keyboard language to Arabic, a message shows and says: please switch back to english keyboard ( in arabic)